# Can I use linear regression on this model y = a/b *x + 1/b

Tags: regression

Can I use linear regression on this model y = a/b *x + 1/b?

y = (1+ax) /b

since a/b and 1/b are related I suspect I cannot use linear regression (least square) directly. Is it possible to transform it to standard linear model?

Comment: Thanks. Actually I think I should have made my question more clear. basically the common calculation for a and b for linear model y = ax+b are derived from taking partial derivatives on a and b assuming a and b are un-related. for example, a = ssxy/ssxx But in this case 2 coefficients a/b and 1/b are related and I suspect if I can assign m = a/b and n = 1/b to make the model y = mx + n to determine n = ybar - m * xbar and m = ssxy/ssxx because of the relationship between m and n. Thanx -Johnny

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you consider $a/b$ and $1/b$ to be "related"? As far as I can tell, the only thing this form of parameterization does is to exclude the possibility of a zero intercept. It does not otherwise impose any kind of relationship between those two coefficients. What, then, are you hoping to achieve with this model that the standard parameterization $\mathbb{E}(y)=\alpha x + \beta$ does not?

Answer (score 11):

Your model(s) are still linear in the coefficients.  You can fit a regular linear regression, then transform the estimated coefficients into the values that you are interested in :

- $b=\frac{1}{\alpha}$
- $a=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$

Answer (score 4):

Your model is not a linear model. Recall that a linear model means that the equation relating $X$ and $E[Y|X]$ is not linear in the variables, but linear in the coefficients. If you estimate the usual linear model you get:

$$ E[Y|X] = a^\prime + b^\prime X $$

You can use a Delta-method approach to estimating the linear model and use the estimated covariance matrix as well as the Jacobian for the change-of-variable

$$ J = \frac{\partial f(a^\prime, b^\prime)}{\partial a^\prime b^\prime}$$

with $f(a^\prime, b^\prime) = $ whatever is necessary to invert the a/b and 1/b example above.

Comment: Thanks AdamO. Yes. I recall linear model means linear in coefficients -Johnny

Comment: (1) Your log-log model is not identifiable; only $\log(a/b)=\log(a)-\log(b)$ is. (2) You ought to point out that your version changes the implicit error structure in the model. (3) Taking the antilog implies the original model was $E[Y|X] = (a/b)X$. That does not seem to correspond to any of the models contemplated in the question.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible to use linear regression?

Comment: @whuber I did overlook that. Oops. Had to edit since it was so egregiously wrong. We *could* rewrite the equation with an offset and use the EM algorithm to estimate the factor of $1/b$. That's a bit contrived, though. I think it's the kind of thing that tends to suggest writing a better model.

Comment: @Johnny by all means you can obtain valid CIs for the $a$ and $b$ of your parametrization using the Delta-method as I alluded to. It is simply a matter of going through the handiwork of obtaining the change-of-variable formulae and obtaining the Jacobian.

Comment: this sounds like nonlinear regression approach.

Comment: Johnny, you ought to take a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148638.