# Is this a linear or non linear model, and why?

Tags: linear, nonlinear

A model $Y=(\beta_0+\beta_1x)^{-1}+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ is to be fitted to the data $(x_1,Y_1), (x_2,Y_2), \dots (x_n,Y_n)$.

Is this a linear or non linear model, and why?

Show how it can be made into a GLM and state the link function?

Any help would be great!

Comment: It is linear in the parameters, So it is a linear model.  However it is undefined at x=0.

Comment: Please add the actual question to the body of post.

Comment: @Michael Please explain what meaning you ascribe to "linear."  As far as I can tell, this model is not linear in *any* of the parameters or its variable $x$ in the standard mathematical or statistical meaning of the term. And why, exactly, would it be undefined at $x=0$? Except when $\beta_0$ also is zero, one can readily make sense of and compute $(\beta_0+\beta_1(0))^{-1}$  Luvspi, have you seen https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148638? It explains the meaning of "linear" regression model.

Comment: I thought the parentheses were missing in the original post.  So only x was raised to the -1 power.

Comment: @whuber - My apologies.

Comment: @Digio No need for that: whatever you might think of the outcome, your analysis was interesting.

Comment: Updated the question. The entire content of the parenthesis is raised to -1 power (inverse?).

Comment: @whuber I had a look at the post above that explains the difference and it is making some sense now. How would I go about getting this model into GLM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a somewhat unusual generalised linear model with a Gaussian response $Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where the mean of the response $\mu$ is linked to the linear predictor $\eta$ via 
$$
g(\mu)=\underbrace{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x}_\eta.
$$
where $g$ is the inverse link function $g(\mu)=1/\mu$,

The linear predictor $\eta$ is clearly linear in $x$ and, as implied by its name, in the regression coefficients $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$.  However, because of the non-linear link function, $\mu=EY$ is non-linear in the model parameters and in $x$.

To fit this in R do `glm(y ~ x, gaussian(link = "inverse"))`.

Comment: Much appreciated. So the model is in fact non-linear that can be put into the GLM form by using the inverse link function?

Comment: @Luvpsi Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Thanks again. Would it require much work to get it into GLM?

Comment: No, you just have to define to vectors `x` and `y` containing the data and then run the above command.

Comment: in the question given I am not given the data to use with R, but rather asked what I would need to do to get it into GLM?

Comment: I am still a bit confused at how I can get this model down to GLM form and what I would need to do to get it there? Any help would be great.