# Is the equation is Linear Regression?

Tags: regression, linear

Employees Salary = 3000 + x(Employee Age)^2,
is this a Linear Regression?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Without more details this is hard to answer as your notation is non-standard and confusing. Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: Perhaps you're trying to inquire about the issues discussed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148638?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for there being a regression, there should be parameters! I will assume 3000 and 1 are in this case

It is linear regression if you consider your "employee age squared" as a variable, so, strictly speaking, it is a linear regression only after a transformation.

In general, there are many ways to transform apparently non-linear models into linear ones by means of one of those (exponential, logs, roots, powers and so on...)