# How can I reformulate this regression model and "linearize" it?

Tags: regression, probability, multiple-regression, inference

I have been given a set of value to perform a linear regression(using matrix method). In order to estimate standard error of variables and the r<sup>2</sup> and I am having trouble reformulating this function to linear method in order to estimate further predictions.

[image: question]

For more clarity to my equation an image to the excel work sheet and the question:

Help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: "I am having trouble" gives us no information about what kind of help you are looking for.

Comment: i need to change the the equation y=theta0+theta1 + ln(x) into a linear form

Comment: It already is linear in the parameters, which is what matters.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148638.

Answer (score 1):

Given $(y,x_1)$, convert your data into $(y,\ln(x_1))$, and run the regression on those latter variables following the model you are given. What part are you stuck on ?