# Why is $Y=\beta_0 x^{\beta_1} e$ a linear model?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, linear, logarithm

Why is $Y=\beta_0 x^{\beta_1} e$ a linear model? When we apply the transform, it becomes $lnY = ln\beta_0+\beta_1 lnx +lne$, and why is it still linear when the $\beta_0$ part is under ln?

Comment: Just give $\log\beta_0$ another name, such as $\gamma_0.$ The two models aren't equivalent, though: think about what happens when $\beta_0$ is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y=\beta_0 x^{\beta_1} e$ is not a linear model, it's a power model that can be linearized to a linear model, $\ln Y = \ln \beta_0+\beta_1 \ln x +\ln e$.

Doing that, and estimating it with least-squares, entail an assumption on the original model: $\ln e \sim \mathcal N (0, \sigma^2)$.
In other words, you assume that the $e$ terms are lognormal-distributed.

Comment: Least-squares estimation does not assume normally distributed errors.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of linear is not on based on the predictors. It's based on the beta's. In your example the predictor is on the power of beta 1 not the beta itself.

Comment: Your characterization of "linear" seems overly restrictive.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148713/919 for a detailed discussion of various possible meanings of "linear model."