# Interview question (incomplete): extension of linear regression (errors in variable)

Tags: regression, errors-in-variables

Here is a interview question I head from others, but I think the information may be not complete and correct. Could anyone help me to modify it?

Question: Suppose $X\sim N(0,1), \epsilon\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y = X+\epsilon,$ calculate the linear regression (`OLR`) coefficient of $Y$ respect to $X.$ How about $Y = X^2 + \epsilon?$

In the `EIV (errors in variable)` I know the assumption is

$$E Y=\eta,\ E X = \xi;\ \eta = \alpha + \beta \xi,$$
$$Y = \alpha + \beta \xi + \epsilon,\ \epsilon\sim n(0,\sigma^2_{\epsilon});\quad X = \xi + \delta,\ \delta\sim n(0,\sigma^2_{\delta})$$
then use MLE to solve the coefficient. In the question, directly write $Y$ as a function of $X,$ then how to define `Linear`?

Comment: There are various definitions of "linear" in this context: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148638/.  But the default assumption is it means that you seek a model for the conditional expectation $E[Y\mid X]$ (that's what "regression" means) as a linear function of $X.$

Comment: but if we use $Y|X,$ then the randomness of $X$ is meanless.

Comment: For regression you are correct that the randomness of $X$ is irrelevant, because *by definition* regression concerns the conditional response of $Y,$ not the joint distribution of $(X,Y).$

Comment: @whuber that is why I mentioned it may be related to the `EIV (errors in variable)` or $X\sim N$ is just a typo...

Comment: I don't think $X\sim N(0,1)$ is a typographical error: *it simply is not relevant to questions of regressing $Y$ against $X.$*