# Do these residuals indicate a nonlinear model?

Tags: regression, residuals

[image: Residual Plot]

Do these residuals indicate that the linearity assumption of linear regression is violated. I know that the constant variance assumption is violated, but I am not sure about the linearity assumption. (this image was taken from https://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/Residual-Plot-Analysis)

Comment: Which "linearity assumption"?  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148713/919 for a discussion of the various things this could mean.

Comment: Difficult to say much without more context, but looks more like heteroskedasticity, search this site!

Comment: There is no obvious violation of the linearity assumption, but one should overlay the LOESS smooth for better visualization.