# Assumptions in Multiple linear regression

Tags: error, assumptions

Is the following assumption in MLR (multiple linear regression) true or false ??

**$\epsilon_i$ is independent of $Y_i$ for i=1,…,n.** Where,

$\epsilon_i$ is the random error in the model
$Y_i$ is the outcome (dependent variable)

let me know your thoughts?
Also what about the opposite assumption which is:

**$Y_i$ is independent of $\epsilon_i$ for i=1,…,n.** ?? is it true or false

Comment: [This site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+assumptions+independ*) will more than fully answer all your questions.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. 
May I ask what do you think about the above-mentioned assumption?

Comment: My answer is posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148713/919.

Comment: So, as I understand this assumption "   is independent of  " is false, because they are both related and   =   -   hat, am I correct? 
and if they are both related, so both assumptions listed above are wrong. Please correct me if I am wrong