# Literature on regression with constraints

Tags: regression

What are some good books or other material that explains how we can do analysis (hypothesis testing, confidence intervals, consistency) of a regression with constrains. For example,
$$y \sim \alpha x_1 + \beta x_2$$ subject to$$f(\alpha) + g(\beta) = 1.$$ A priori, I am also interested in non-linear regressions.
I am aware of the following [pdf](https://chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://home.iitk.ac.in/%7Eshalab/econometrics/Chapter6-Econometrics-RegressionAnalysisUnderLinearRestrictions.pdf) about regression + Lagrange multiplier, but I was more interested in a book.

Comment: Standard analysis wouldn't change, only portion of the analysis would be to use constrained optimisers in finding the values of $\alpha, \beta$, i.e., [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming).

Comment: It depends on the kind of constraint.  A linear equality like the example here doesn't change anything.  You can see this by substituting $\beta=1-\alpha$ in the model, which yields a comparable model with one less parameter.  What matters are whether (1) any constraints are nonlinear and (2) whether any are *inequalities.*  Finally, "non-linear regression" has several different meanings: please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148638 for an account of the distinctions.

Comment: Thank you. But how exactly can I perform statistical inference under non-linear constraint on paramteres?

Comment: If you want to study the problem in such generality, then seek out books on constrained optimization.