# Is a quadratic model fitted with OLS still a linear regression model?

Tags: regression, linear-model

Looking at [this](https://quantifyinghealth.com/quadratic-term-in-regression/) the functional form "quadratic model" is introduced as a linear regression model does not assume linearity between IV and DV and only has to be linear in parameters. Is it still a linear model when fitted with OLS?

Comment: See here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/597445/56940

Comment: As a heads up, a model is linear regardless of estimation approach (e.g., OLS vs minimizing the sum of the absolute value of the residuals). Indeed, a model is linear whether you estimate the coefficients or not!

Comment: Curious even when one introduces X^2 the parameters still enter the model linear don't they. TBH I do not really agree with the accepted answer you suggested @utobi

Comment: @cs0815 could you explain _why_ you disagree?

Comment: X^2 is feature engineered - the parameters therefore still enter the model linearly making it a linear model?