# If the error term in a regression is squared can it still be a linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear, error

So basically I’ve been taught that in a linear regression model the parameters alpha and beta cannot be squared when defining the equation of our model, does this also apply for the error term (epsilon) or only for the parameters?

Comment: Can you give a real example where you would want to square the error term? What is the purpose? Do you mean that the errors cannot be negative?

Comment: It’s a question I found online, no example provided :(. The question wanted to know if the following model was a linear regression model: Y = alpha + beta*X + epsilon^2

Comment: According to my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148713/919, *sort of.* The problem is that because $E[\epsilon^2]\ne 0,$ it does double duty by modeling a *systematic* error as well as a random error.  Under the usual *iid* conditions and supposing the error terms have a common second moment $\mu_2=E[\epsilon_i^2],$ we could rewrite the model as $Y = (\alpha+\mu_2)+\beta X + (\epsilon^2-\mu_2).$ That would be an ordinary regression setting with a non-Gaussian mean-zero conditional distribution.