# least squares in regression with covariate-dependent model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, linear-model, linear

Classical least squares results in regression in statistics state that if $(Y, X)$ follow a model where $$\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X=x] = \alpha  + \beta x,$$ we can estimate $\beta$ from a random sample using LS explicitly as the second component of $\hat{\beta} = (\textbf{X}^t\textbf{X})^{-1}\textbf{X}^t\textbf{Y}$, where $\textbf{X}$ is the matrix of ones and $X_i$.

My question is the following: Let $(Y, X, Z)$ follow a model $$\mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z=z, X=x] = (\alpha x) + (\beta x) z.$$

Consider a random sample from $(Y, X, Z)$. Can we estimate $\hat{\beta}$ and give an explicit expression for it?

Comment: It is challenging to search this site for a formula -- but in this case, because the formula appears in over ten thousand posts, it's not hard to find!  [This restricted search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+beta+formula+-logistic+-error++is%3Aanswer) worked for me.  You might also be interested in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148638.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to call this problem a duplicate. I think OP is probably a little unsure how to work two parameters $X,Z$ into this model. What OP needs to realise is $Y=\alpha X+\beta XZ$ is still linear in terms of the parameters $\theta=(\alpha, \beta)$. The formula of $\hat{\theta}=(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Y}$ can still be used, just with $x_i$ and $x_iz_i$ as the columns of $\mathbf{X}$.