Determining if a given regression model is a general linear model
I came across this question while studying. It asks to determine if the following regression models are general linear models, or if they can be transformed in such a way that they become general linear models. The way I understand linear regression is that it is linear in the regression parameters and not the covariates. Hence, the general linear models can be written:
$\begin{align}
Y_i=\beta_0+\sum_{i}{\beta_k\cdot c_i}+\epsilon_i
\end{align}$
where $c_i$'s act as coefficients to the function of $\beta_0,\beta_1,...$
The regression model being asked to analyze is the following:
$\begin{align}
Y_i=ln(\beta_1\cdot x_{i1})+\beta_2\cdot x_{i2}+\epsilon_i
\end{align}$
Immediately, this doesnt appear to be in a general linear form, and the only manipulation that seems to be productive would be
$\begin{align}
Y_i=ln(\beta_1)+ln(x_{i1})+\beta_2\cdot x_{i2}+\epsilon_i
\end{align}$
I feel I could argue that the the $\beta_{1}$ term acts as an intercept and the $ln(x_{i1})$ term can move to the other side to fit the above linearity criteria, but the fact that the regression parameter is being transformed at all is sending red flags to this being a proper general linear model. The solution manual says that this is without any further explanation. Any insight would be greatly appreciated

You will find your question answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148713/919, with a caveat: the relation $\log(\beta_1,x_{i1})=\log(\beta_1)+\log(x_{i1})$ holds only when both terms are positive.  Your textbook likely (implicitly) assumes this. Nevertheless, given the implication that $\beta_1,x_{i1}$ is positive, the correct relationship is $$\log(\beta_1,x_{i1})=\log(|\beta_1|)+\log(|x_{i1}|).$$

I don’t understand how a transformation of $\beta$ can constitute a linear equation. Like is $\beta^2$/$e^{\beta}$ acceptable for linear regression? Does this not change the inherent relationship between the covariates?

Perhaps a closer reading of the link will help you with that: it explains three different senses of "linear" in this context and shows how such a parameter transformation can be (and usually is) just fine, because all it amounts to is a change in the numerical expression of the parameters.  By referring to a "relationship between the covariates" you appear to confuse a parameter like $\beta$ with the data: only the latter can be considered a covariate.
